# How to write to the log file using Laravel 4 artisan command?

Tags: logging, laravel, laravel-4, command, error-logging

So the below code pulls the data I'm looking for, and dumps it to the command line, but it won't write to the log files... any clues to how I SHOULD be doing this?

```
public function fire()
{
Log::info('Starting Pull', array('Start Pull' => 'Begin');
$this->line('Pulling Data From Source.');
$sites=Site::all();
foreach($sites as $site){
        Log::info('Doing Pull for', array('data Pull' => print_r($site->tag,true)));
    }
    $this->line('Completed');
     Log::info('End Pull', array('End Pull' => 'Done');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're looking at the right log?

Laravel 4 adds the Server API (´php_sapi_name()´) being used to run it. So if you're using Apache 2, you should see files named as:

```
log-apache2handler-YYYY-MM-DD.txt
```

When accessing your app via web interface; and

```
log-cli-YYYY-MM-DD.txt
```

When accessing your app via a command line interface (i.e. Artisan).